# Serialize Dictionary without property name with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm using

```
var myResponse = new Response(myDictionary);
string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myResponse);
```

where

```
internal class Response 
{
    public Response (Dictionary<string, string> myDict) 
    {
        MyDict = myDict;
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> MyDict { get; private set; }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
{
  "MyDict": 
  { 
     "key" : "value", 
     "key2" : "value2"
  }
}
```

what I want to get is:

```
{
    "key" : "value", 
    "key2" : "value2"
}
```

`

is that possible with Newtonsoft.Json?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're serializing the entire object. if you just want the output you specified then just serialize the dictionary:

```
string response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myResponse.MyDict);
```

this will output:

```
{"key":"value","key2":"value2"}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to work and serialize the entire class, and not the dictionary only, you can write a simple class which inherits `JsonConverter` which tells the serializer how to serialize the object:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ResponseConverter))]
public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Foo { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(
            JsonReader jsonReader, Type type, object obj, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
            JsonWriter jsonWriter, object obj, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var response = (Response)obj;
        foreach (var kvp in response.Foo)
        {
            jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(kvp.Key);
            jsonWriter.WriteValue(kvp.Value);
        }
    }
    public override bool CanConvert(Type t)
    {
        return t == typeof(Response);
    }
}
```

Now this:

```
void Main()
{
    var response = new Response();
    response.Foo = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "1", "1" }  };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

Will output:

```
{ "1":"1" }
```

Although a bit verbose for such a simple task, but this will let you work with the object itself without worrying about serializing the dictionary only.